# Google sheets Countif formula

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to write a formula to count:

if both cell A1 and cell B1 both have text then count 1
=COUNTIF(A1="v",B1="v") then C1=1

But if both cells are empy then return value 0
for some reason if both cells are empty I get the value of 1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) only takes a single criterion, so what you want is probably [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en);

Your condition can then be written as;

```
=COUNTIFS(A1, "*", B1, "*")
```